# Zero downtime deployment for nodejs

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy

At my company we have a nodejs api, with a front end applcation.

Currently it is a systemd service, and a nodejs cluster.

When we deploy a new version, we restart the systemd service and the service goes down for a few seconds.

Which leads to refused orders without warnings or explications, and unavailability of the service, etc.

The infra is structured like this :

Machine A: nginx reverse proxying to machine B on port 6081

MAchine B: varnish listening on port 6081, proxying to a nodeJS cluster on port 5000

The service does not requires high scalability.

I would like to improve this to zero downtime deployment.

At the moment I know two options for zero downtime :

- pm2 cluster which uses nodejs’s cluster
- A docker container but in my understanding it does require an orchestrator ?

We use gitlab. The docker image could be built from the CI/CD.

What are other options ?

Comment: Kubernetes can be an option if your app architecture is right for micro-services-like orchastration, but you are probably better off looking into Blue-green methodologies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-green_deployment . I'm afraid that SU may not be the best community for questions on ultra-high availability service maintenance operations.

Comment: Another option is Nomad https://www.nomadproject.io/

Comment: I took a look at kubernetes and nomad, it’s very abstract for a front end developper. It’s out of my skillset. Thanks anyway.

Comment: so ultra-high availability is an Infrastructure concern, so you will need to be working with the folks who run the servers pretty much any way you go. its not an appdev problem, its a hosting problem/